# Error while compiling kernel

Tags: android, linux-kernel, arm

I was compiling a Kernel for an Android Phone and got this errror:

```
  LINK    vmlinux
  LD      vmlinux.o
  MODPOST vmlinux.o
  GEN     .version
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  UPD     include/generated/compile.h
  CC      init/version.o
  LD      init/built-in.o
drivers/built-in.o: In function `synaptics_rmi4_probe':
/home/taco/android/kernel/cyanogen/msm8916/drivers/input/touchscreen/synaptics_i2c_rmi4.c:3824: undefined reference to `init_tp_fm_info'
drivers/built-in.o: In function `iris_fops_release':
/home/taco/android/kernel/cyanogen/msm8916/drivers/media/radio/radio-iris.c:5223: undefined reference to `fm_smd_enable'
Makefile:805: recipe for target 'vmlinux' failed
```

Everything was downloaded and synced correctly. I think this is a problem with my defconfig. I was using msm8909-perf_defconfig

Thanks.

This is the defconfig I was using: https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_kernel_cyanogen_msm8916/blob/cm-14.1/arch/arm/configs/msm8909-perf_defconfig

Comment: If the earlier `defconfig` used to compile successfully for you, can you use that and try `clean` `build` once?

Comment: this was my first using this defconfig.

Comment: @TheOddTaco Did you edit this config file manually or use one of the menuconfig utilities to generate it?  Those utilities are good at resolving inter-dependencies.